# Problemas com concatenações usando jQuery, para inserir parâmetros com append

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ao colocar aspas de diferentes formas para ser possível a concatenação, aparece um erro pelo Elements no navegador Chromer, eu gostaria que dentro dos parâmetros, as informações ficassem com aspas simples. Se alguém poder me ajudar nessa questão de concatenar, seria uma grande gratidão.

```js
for(linha = 0;  16 > linha; linha++){
//CARREGAMENTO DOS DADOS LOCAIS DOS FILMES
$('.line_recent').append("<a href='" + filme[linha].src_filme + "' onmouseover='info('"+filme[linha].nome_filme+"', '" + filme[linha].idade_filme + "', '"+ filme[linha].descricao_filme +"','"+ filme[linha].tipo_traducao +"', '"+ filme[linha].ano +"', '"+  filme[linha].capa_filme+"');'><div class='box'><div id='box_img'> <img src='data:image/png;base64, " + filme[linha].img_filme +"'> </div></div></a>");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reserve um minuto do teu tempo para ler sobre [Interpolação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) é muito simples e torna o teu código mais legível, exemplo:

```js
const filme = {
  title: "I'm a movie",
  description: "That's my story",
  release: 2020,
  duration: 220,
  country: "USA"
}

const detalhes = `The movie "${filme.title}" with the history "${filme.description}", was released in ${filme.release} on ${filme.country} with the duration of ${filme.duration} minutes`;

console.log(detalhes);
```

Com a interpolação você usa a crase o que permite interpolar textos e variáveis de maneira simples sem ter que adicionar `+` para cada concatenção, fica mais fácil também o uso das aspas ou apóstrofo.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica! Estou muito agradecido, seguirei estes passos de interpolação.